# How do i get an integer form of the value from gtk+ scale?

Tags: gtk

How do i get the integer form of the current value from a scale in gtk+? I'm using c and most of the documentation i've come across talk python. I don't find the gtk documentation particular helpful. I am trying to make a simple volume scale. I've looked for questions similar to this but i haven't found one that helps.

Comment: The C documentation is [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html). Note that GtkScale is derived from GtkRange (the class hierarchy is on each class page), so you will need to also look at that class's documentation to find the method you want: [`gtk_range_get_value()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRange.html#gtk-range-get-value). Call like `gtk_range_get_value(GTK_RANGE(myScale))` to avoid compiler warnings.

Comment: @andlabs, please reply as an answer the above comment so i may accept it. Thanks for help, it is working in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry for the late response.)

The C documentation is [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html). Note that GtkScale is derived from GtkRange (the class hierarchy is on each class page), so you will need to also look at that class's documentation to find the method you want: [`gtk_range_get_value()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRange.html#gtk-range-get-value). Call like `gtk_range_get_value(GTK_RANGE(myScale))` to avoid compiler warnings.